# node.js request returning different when called from express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a function `getPropertyData` that takes in a URL and a callback function. It calls the URL, get the contents, parses it (`buildDataObject`), transforms it (`transformData`), and calls the callback:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const express = require('express');

var getPropertyData = function(url, callback) {
  request(url, function(err, res, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    console.log("Received data (html length): " + body.length)

    var data = buildDataObject($);
    console.log("Parsed data (object length): " + Object.keys(data).length);

    var property = transformData(data);

    callback(property);
  });
};

var buildDataObject = function($) {
  data = {}

  // Populate data object with data from response.
  // will return {} if no data was found to parse.

  return data;
};

var transformData = function(data) {
  if(Object.keys(data).length != 0) {
    return {"message":"success"}
  } else {
    return {"message":"no data received"}
  }
}
```

When I call this function directly:

```
getPropertyData(url, function(result) {
  console.log(result);
})
```

The following gets printed to the console:

```
Received data (html length): 323948
Parsed data (object length): 72
<Expected result>
```

However, when I call this function from an express route definition:

```
var app = express()

...

app.get('/property', function(req, response) {
  getPropertyData(req.query.url, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    response.json(result);
  });
});
```

This gets printed to the console instead:

```
Received data (html length): 17026
Parsed data (object length): 0
<Unexpected result>
```

Why is the data received when call the same URL have a length of over 300k when calling the function directly, but under 20k when calling the function from inside an express route? What do I need to do to insure I get the same 300k+ lines when calling from inside an express route?

Comment: Can you confirm the url you are calling in both cases is identical? (log it)  Maybe log the content (or first 500 lines) of the response, see if that gives you a clue?

Comment: My guess would be that you aren't escaping the URL correctly on your request so `req.query.url` isn't the URL you think it is.

Comment: @skirtle, please post that as the answer and I will accept. Thanks for your help.